# Handling clicks of Dynamic pickers inside loop react-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, picker

i am creating dynamic pickers inside my code , the number of pickers are based on response under my configurable Array.I am able to create pickers but the problem i am facing that if i update any of the picker it resets the values of all pickers immediately , i know when i call setState function the Render Method get called again manage items as per the current state value , but it's my requirement in project , so can any one suggest me a way to do that , it's very critical for me.

**Here my code** :-

```
loadData(item) {
    return item.options.map(user => (
      <Picker.Item label={user.label} value={user.id} />
    ))
  }

  renderConfigurableProductDetail() {
      array = this.props.ProductDetailState.productData.configurable;
    {
    return array.map((item) => {
    if(item.label!="Size"){
      return <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "white", flexDirection: "column", marginTop: 8 }}>
        <CustomText style={{ fontSize: 16, fontFamily: "futuraLigtBt", marginLeft: 6, paddingLeft: 15, paddingRight: 15, paddingTop: 5, paddingBottom: 5 }}>
          {item.label}
        </CustomText>
        <Picker
          selectedValue={this.state.selectedDropDownValue}
          onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => this.onClickDropdown(itemValue,itemIndex)}>
          {this.loadData(item)}
        </Picker>
      </View>;
    }
    })
  }
  };

onClickDropdown(data,index){
    alert(data+" "+index)
    this.setState({ selectedDropDownValue: data});
  }
```

**2nd Approach** :-

```
loadData(item) {
    return item.options.map(user => (
      <Picker.Item label={user.label} value={user.id} />
    ))
  }

  renderConfigurableProductDetail() {
    let array=[];
    if (CustomConfigArray.length>0){
      array = CustomConfigArray;
    }else{
      array = this.props.ProductDetailState.productData.configurable;
    }
    return array.map((item,i) => {
    if(item.label!="Size"){
      return <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "white", flexDirection: "column", marginTop: 8 }}>
        <CustomText style={{ fontSize: 16, fontFamily: "futuraLigtBt", marginLeft: 6, paddingLeft: 15, paddingRight: 15, paddingTop: 5, paddingBottom: 5 }}>
          {item.label}
        </CustomText>
        <Picker
          selectedValue={this.state.selectedDropDownValue[i]}
          onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => this.onClickDropdown(itemValue,itemIndex)}>
          {this.loadData(item)}
        </Picker>

      </View>;
    }
    })
  };

onClickDropdown(value,index){
    let selectValue = this.state.selectedDropDownValue;
    selectValue[index] = value;
    this.setState({
      selectedDropDownValue: selectValue
    });
  }
```

**Configurable Array** :-

```
"configurable": [{
              "id": "142",
              "code": "size",
              "label": "Size",
              "options": [{
                "attribute_id": "142",
                "atribute_code": "size",
                "id": "171",
                "label": "XL",
                "products": [
                  "2071",
                  "2074"
                ]
              }, {
                "attribute_id": "142",
                "atribute_code": "size",
                "id": "172",
                "label": "L",
                "products": [
                  "2072"
                ]
              }]
            },
            {
              "id": "93",
              "code": "color",
              "label": "Color",
              "options": [{
                "attribute_id": "93",
                "atribute_code": "color",
                "id": "50",
                "label": "Blue",
                "products": [
                  "2071"
                ]
              },
              {
                "attribute_id": "93",
                "atribute_code": "color",
                "id": "60",
                "label": "Black",
                "products": [
                  "2072"
                ]
              }, {
                "attribute_id": "93",
                "atribute_code": "color",
                "id": "64",
                "label": "Cyna",
                "products": [
                  "2072"
                ]
              }, {
                "attribute_id": "93",
                "atribute_code": "color",
                "id": "61",
                "label": "White",
                "products": [
                  "2071",
                  "2074"
                ]
              }
              ]
            },
            {
              "id": "148",
              "code": "format",
              "label": "Format",
              "options": [{
                "attribute_id": "148",
                "atribute_code": "format",
                "id": "102",
                "label": "Download",
                "products": [
                  "2072",
                  "2071",
                  "2074"
                ]
              },
              {
                "attribute_id": "148",
                "atribute_code": "format",
                "id": "103",
                "label": "File",
                "products": [
                  "2071",
                  "2074"
                ]
              }
              ]
            }
            ]
```

Please let me know if there is a way to achieve this , I Goggled alot but does not found anything which can get fit in my code.So i am here to seek your help

Regards

Comment: Can you please post the response of configurable array, It might help.

Comment: @AkshayAggarwal , Please check the updated one

Comment: Please tell me one thing, Why your map method is inside curly braces in method renderConfigurableProductDetail() and also where are you calling this method.

Comment: Does curly braces put any effect in looping ? and renderConfigurableProductDetail() is inside render method. Onremoving curly braces the functionality remains same.

Comment: When new state depends on previous state you should use the format `setState((prevState, props) => {})` see reference in [the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate).
 In any way you should never mutate state directly and this is what this line does `selectValue[index] = value` since `selectValue` is just a reference to `this.state`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were close but not quite there. Every time you change a value you are overwritten the state value for all pickers. To fix this please consider doing below changes.

```
// load selectedDropDownValue data from state with the item's id
// pass the item value to the change function
<Picker
  selectedValue={this.state.selectedDropDownValue[item.id]}
  onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => this.onClickDropdown(itemValue, itemIndex, item)}
>
  {this.loadData(item)}
</Picker>
```

---

```
onClickDropdown(data, index, item){
  // save each items selected data with their id
  this.setState((prevState) => {
    const { selectedDropDownValue } = Object.assign({}, prevState.selectedDropDownValue, { [item.id]: data});
    return { selectedDropDownValue };
  });
}
```

Comment: your answer is similar to my question but I didn't understand it properly . can you please solve my question its important for me . any help would be appreciated
[my question link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74446229/how-to-show-selected-item-for-each-picker-component-with-api-in-react-native)

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem, but not being to resolve using the above solution.
If i console the "item.id" in OnClickDropDown its the id of last "Picker".

```
<View style={styles.inputContainer}>
                <Text style={{fontSize: 16, fontWeight: 'bold'}}>
                  {obj.cmdParams[key].title}
                </Text>
                <Picker
                  selectedValue={this.state.selectedDropDownValue[item.id]? 
     this.state.selectedDropDownValue[item.id]: ''}
                  onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) =>
                    this.onClickDropdown(itemValue, itemIndex, item)
                  }>
                  {this.renderPicker(item.options.default)}
                </Picker>
              </View>

     renderPicker(options) {
     return options.map(obj => {
    return <Picker.Item label={obj.label} value={obj.value} />;
     });
    }
   onClickDropdown(data, index, item) {
// save each items selected data with their id
  this.setState((prevState) => {
    const { selectedDropDownValue } = Object.assign({}, 
  prevState.selectedDropDownValue, { [item.id]: data});
    return { selectedDropDownValue };
  });
  console.log(item.id)
}
```